Closed form of the following sum of binomial coefficients.
Let $n>1$ be a positive integer. I want to know whether there is a closed form for the following expression.
$$\sum_{\begin{array}{cc}
     1\le k\le n-1\\
     gcd(k,n)=1
\end{array}}{n\choose k}$$
What I already know is the sum of the following expression.
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}=2^n$$
It is clear that if $n$ is prime, then $\displaystyle\sum_{\begin{array}{cc}
     1\le k\le n-1\\
     gcd(k,n)=1
\end{array}}{n\choose k}=2^n-2$. Also it can be observed that $\displaystyle\sum_{\begin{array}{cc}
     1\le k\le n-1\\
     gcd(k,n)=1
\end{array}}{n\choose k}=2\displaystyle\sum_{\begin{array}{cc}
     1\le k\le \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor\\
     gcd(k,n)=1
\end{array}}{n\choose k}$, since $gcd(k,n)=1$ if and only if $gcd(n-k,n)=1$ and $n\choose k$=$n\choose n-k$. So it is enough to find the closed form of the sum (if there is any)
$$\sum_{\begin{array}{cc}
     1\le k\le \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor\\
     gcd(k,n)=1
\end{array}}{n\choose k}$$
Any help would be appreciated.

"So it is enough to find the closed form" - what makes you think there is a closed form?

@DietrichBurde I think the OP clearly stated he wants to know whether there is a closed form

Then the answer is no. But there are good estimates.

@DietrichBurde That's what I want to know actually. Okay, I edited the question.

You are interested on the terms of the sequence A056188 on OEIS (oeis.org/A056188). There is not much information about it there, though.

This is sequence A056188 in OEIS  (Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences). No closed-form formula is mentionned in the corresponding article.
Here is a (log-scale) representation of the sequence (blue curve) in comparison of the (log-scale) sequence $2^n$, naturally represented as a line (red). Few hope to improve the upper bound of the sequence.


Is there any good bound for this expression? Obviously $2^n$ is an upper bound. But that's not what I am asking about.

See the graphical representation I just added to my answer. It displays an unexpected kind of "regularity".

Let us define the sequence $a(n)$ by
$$
a(n) = \sum_{\begin{array}{cc}
     1\le k\le n-1\\
     gcd(k,n)=1
\end{array}}{n\choose k}
$$
It is perhaps worth mentioning that the sequence $a(n)$ is
listed at OEIS at A056188, and starts with
$$
1, 2, 6, 8, 30, 12, 126, 128, 342, 260, 2046, 1608, 8190, 4760, 15840, 32768, 131070, 80820.
$$
A closed formula is not mentioned, which usually means that it is not known.

I see we are on the same wavelength...

@JeanMarie I just noticed we did the same, yes :)
